# ValueAnimator in Android and how to make it increase by one each second

Tags: java, android, counting, stopwatch

I'm working on this android app...and I have a textview, where I'd like to count UP. In this textview I have the statement "This page was refreshed X seconds ago". Every 20 seconds I'd like it to restart its countup from 0.

I've implemented a function which uses the ValueAnimator class. However, I'm not sure how to make the ValueAnimator increase the integer value by 1 every second. I'd like it to count up like a clock's second hand 1...2..3...4..5......20. Right now its counting up incredibly fast...and I want to slow it waaayyyy down. 1 count per second.

Please how do I do this? I've looked at some of the method calls for ValueAnimator, and I'm not sure how to slow it down...right now it's so fast.

Also, where would I add a method call, lets say, everytime the counter gets to 20 seconds? Lets say I want to call refreshView() when it gets to 20, before it starts all over.

Thank you for your time, and thanks for your help.

The ValueAnimator class:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator

In my method I have:

```
    ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(initialValue, finalValue);
    valueAnimator.setDuration(10000);

    valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
            textview.setText("This page was refreshed " + valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue().toString() + " seconds ago");
        }
    });
    valueAnimator.start();
    // Repeat 100 times
    valueAnimator.setRepeatCount(100);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ValueAniamtor is used for animation. Animation are refreshed at very high rate. I don't think that you can count seconds with a valueAnimator.

In one of my apps i use a Timer to refresh periodically a textView.

```
final TextView textview=findViewById(R.id.tv);
    new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        int value=0; //start at 0
        @Override
        public void run() {
            value++ ; 
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { //only the main thread can touch his views
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    textview.setText("This page was refreshed " + value + " seconds ago"); //refresh text

                }
            });
        }
    }, 0, 1000); //reschedule every 1000 milliseconds


}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you